# What is the regular expression to remove spaces in SOLR

Tags: solr

In a Regex, how to remove all the leading, trailing and where ever spaces exist in SOLR.
To remove special characters, we can have the PatternReplaceFilterFactory as

```
<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="([^a-z])" replacement="" replace="all" />
```

What pattern value will be formed to remove the spaces whereever it comes.

Comment: Why you want to remove spaces? Don't you use tokenizer?

Comment: What does you field type configuration look like ? do you want to replace all whitespaces with nothing ? won't it cause issues ? what do you want to achieve ?

Answer (score 3):

I don't know SOLR but based on your example I guess you could just do

`<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(\s+)" replacement="" replace="all" />` to remove all spaces

**or**

`<filter class="solr.PatternReplaceFilterFactory" pattern="(^\s+|\s+$)" replacement="" replace="all" />` to remove just leading and trailing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

Use the trim filter to remove leading and trailing spaces. http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.TrimFilterFactory

just replacing everything not a-z with nothing will cause strange things to happen and is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

solr.TrimFilterFactory  , can be used to remove leading and trailing spaces without regex.