# Solr - Match sentence beginning with a particular word

Tags: java, solr, solr4

Any tips on how this is done?

I've tried using the `PatternTokenizerFactory`, but it's not working as expected.

Is it possible to do this without writing a `custom tokenizer`?

Comment: can you show us how you use PatternTokenizerFactory and what is not working with it?

Answer (score 1):

you can tokenize the field in question using KeyWordTokenizerFactory and then do wildcard search

http://solr.pl/en/2010/12/20/wildcard-queries-and-how-solr-handles-them/

provided that you are not doing any other operation which does not work with the above Tokenizer.

Another way is a roundabout way. You can create a copyfield which will have its spaces stripped out using the following technique (or some other) :-

[What is the regular expression to remove spaces in SOLR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9427130/what-is-the-regular-expression-to-remove-spaces-in-solr)

You can then tokenize that copyfield using WhiteSpaceTokenizer (which essentially creates one token only since the copyfield values have no space) and then do a wildcard search on it.

The second approach might fail in some of the cases (for eg.  "wor them" will match "worth*" after the spaces are stripped)